# Put text into AVFrame

Tags: c++, text, ffmpeg, drawtext

I use the FFmpeg library and I have an object of `AVFrame` which uses the format `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`. I'd like to put a text on such frame in a given location, font size etc.

I cannot find a proper API in FFmpeg library to do it, there is a function `drawtext`, but it's a static function inside a .c file (not a header).

How to do it with FFmpeg and if it's not possible, what other library I should use instead?

Comment: You might look at OpenCV instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts Instead or in the sense of creating `cv::Mat` object initialized with `AVFrame`'s data, which is modified by `cv::putText`?

Comment: drawtext is a filter which can be used as in this example: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_filter_video.c.